# Bootstrap Modal and Badges

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following lines of code in my webpage - [example/demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waOXJR?editors=101).

HTML:

```
<p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#messagesModal"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge">2</span></a>
</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="messagesModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Messages</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert fade in">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
          <strong>Message 01</strong>:
          <p>Lipsum Ipsum
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="alert fade in">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
          <strong>Message 02</strong>:
          <p>Ipsum Lipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I update the badge to represent the correct amount of messages in the modal?

For example, when the user closes or removes a message in the modal, the badge will go from displaying the number `2` to `1`?

Also, is it possible to display the text "*There are no more messages.*" when all of the messages have been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I've spend some time, but all that you should do for now:

1. populate message array with your actual data;
2. add some actual AJAX for removing messages.

So...

```js
$(function() {
    var informer = $("#messageInformer a");
    var refreshBadge = function(messageCount) {
        var badge = informer.find(".badge");
        if (messageCount > 0) {
            if (!badge.length) {
                informer.text("Messages ");
                informer.append("<span class=\"badge\">" + messageCount + "</span>");
            } else {
                badge.text(messageCount);
            }
        } else {
            informer.text("No messages");
        }
    };

    var buildMessage = function(message) {
        var htmlMessage = "<div class=\"alert fade in\">";
        htmlMessage += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-lable=\"close\" data-id=\"" + message.id + "\">&times;</a>";
        htmlMessage += "<strong>" + message.title + "</strong>:";
        htmlMessage += "<p>" + message.text + "</p>";
        return htmlMessage;
    }

    // There should be real data
    var messages = [
        { id: "1", title: "Message 01", text: "Lipsum Ipsum" },
        { id: "2", title: "Message 02", text: "Ipsum Lipsum" }];

    refreshBadge(messages.length);

    informer.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalBody = $(".modal-body");
        modalBody.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            modalBody.append(buildMessage(messages[i]));
        }
    });

    $("body").delegate(".alert .close", "click", function() {
        var messageId = $(this).data("id");
        // There should be some AJAX possibly
        messages = messages.filter(function(el) {
            return el.id != messageId;
        });
        if (messages.length == 0) {
            $("#messagesModal").modal("hide");
        }
        refreshBadge(messages.length);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#messagesModal" id="messageInformer"><a href="#">Messages <span class="badge"></span></a>
</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="messagesModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Messages</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @joe_young Just full answer.

Comment: @user1752759 I prefer to keep markup in html (not as value of object property) since it can be easily used as html-template for something like Ractive.js.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//Find message number initially, before editing
    $(".badge").text($(".alert").length);     

//when the modal is closed
    $('#messagesModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {    
//Set .badge text equal to the length of the .alert array, i.e the number of messages
    $(".badge").text($(".alert").length);       

//If there are no '.alert' divs, i.e. no messages
    if ($(".alert").length == 0) {      
        $(".badge").text("No messages");
    }
});
```

This takes all the `.alert` elements (messages) into an array, and sees how long that array is (i.e. how many messages there are).
Then, it updates `.badge` to reflect that number.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/62hbqmtp/

Comment: But modal is still popped up. And I don't think that taking of HTML-content is a good approach.